# Pin in button throwing error on iPad with Safari

Tags: php, pinterest

I am using the pin it button script to display pin it button on hover.

It's working fine on desktop.
But it throwing error on iPad's Safari.

The error: "Safari cannot open the page. because the address is invalid."

I am using code like this:

```
<div class="pin-it-hover">
   <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo current_url(); ?>&media=   <?php echo site_url($imagepath); ?>&description=<?php echo $description; ?>"
    data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none">
   <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Included script only once.

```
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async  src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

CSS used:

```
.pin-it-hover {
    right: 20px;
    top :20px ;   
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.outerdiv:hover .pin-it-hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Any suggestion?
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: use `http:` like this  `http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js`

Answer (score 1):

Use `http:` in front of URLs or remove `//` in every urls like below.

`http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js` or `assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js`

instead of `//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js`

```
<div class="pin-it-hover">
   <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo current_url(); ?>&media=   <?php echo site_url($imagepath); ?>&description=<?php echo $description; ?>"
    data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-config="none">
   <img src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

I think this will helps you.

Comment: did you use url with `http` or just remove `//`? Put your JS url in browser with `http` and see browser response.

Comment: this is js output so works fine. Did you add `http:` in `a` `href` link and `img src`.